# Why is there a PATH difference depending on how you open PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, path-variables

My path looks like this:
[image]
The top (selected) path contains pandoc.exe and the third from the top (anaconda3) contains pandoc.exe. So the top folder should take priority.

If I launch PowerShell simply by launching "Windows PowerShell.exe", and type `gcm pandoc` I get the top PATH for pandoc.exe:
[image]

If I launch PowerShell by shift-right-clicking in explorer and selecting "Open PowerShell window here", and type `gcm pandoc.exe`, I get the Anaconda PATH for pandoc.exe:
[image]

What gives? Why does it matter in what way I launch PowerShell?

Comment: 1) there isn't a single PATH; environment variables are inherited from the launching process, so they can be different for every process. See if `$env:path` shows up differently in the two powershell sessions. 2) try the trace in https://stackoverflow.com/a/22261212/478656 to see where PS is looking for executables

Comment: I can reproduce if 1) the directory `.` is in the path and 2) the current directory contains the executable in question.

Comment: If I run `trace-command -name CommandDiscovery -command ls -PSHost` I get identical results in both consoles.

If I run `echo $Env:PATH` in both consoles, I get same results except for:

Console 1 opened from context menu:
%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin

Console 2 opened normally:
C:\Users\s113093\.dnx\bin
C:\Users\s113093\AppData\Roaming\local\bin

I.e. crucially it has the `C:\Users\s113093\AppData\Roaming\local\bin` path that makes all the difference.

Comment: @GandalfSaxe: Is `%USERPROFILE%\.dnx\bin` really reported as such, with the environment-variable reference _unexpanded_?

Comment: It is reported exactly as such in the PowerShell that was launched with Shift+F10 -> Open PoweShell window here.