# PowerShell module-qualified names and Command Prefix

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to make use of module-qualified names[1] and a `DefaultCommandPrefix` and not have it break if the module is imported with `Import-Module -Prefix SomethingElse`. Maybe I'm just doing something really wrong here, or those two features aren't meant to be used together.

Inside the main module file using "`ModuleName\Verb-PrefixNoun args...`" works as long as "Prefix" matches the `DefaultCommandPrefix` in the manifest (the module-qualified syntax seems to require the prefix used for the import[2]). But importing the module with a different prefix, all module-qualified references inside the module breaks.

After a bit of searching and trial and error, the least horrible solution I've managed to get working is to use something like the following hackish solution. But, I can't help wonder if there isn't some better way that automatically handles the prefix (just as `Import-Module` obviously manages to add the prefix, my first naive though was that using just `ModuleName\Verb-Noun` would automatically append any prefix to the noun, but evidently not[2].

So this is the hack I came up with, that looks up the modules prefix and appends it, then using "." or "&" to expand/invoke the command:

```bsh
# (imagine this code in the `ModuleName.psm1`, and a manifest with some `DefaultCommandPrefix`)

Function MQ {
    param (
        [Parameter()][string]
        $Verb,
        [Parameter()][string]
        $Noun,
        [string]
        $Module='ModuleName'
    )
    "$Module\$Verb-$((Get-Module $Module).Prefix)$Noun"
}

Function Verb-Noun {
    # This works even when importing with a prefix,
    # but can I be guaranteed that it's not some
    # other module's cmdlet?
    Verb-OtherNoun 1 2 3 '...'

    #ModuleName\Verb-OtherNoun 1 2 3 '...'
    . (MQ 'Verb' 'OtherNoun') 1 2 3 '...'
    # or:
    & (MQ 'Verb' 'OtherNoun') 1 2 3 '...'
}
```

(`MQ` could be made more user friendly by also accepting a single string `MQ "Verb-Noun"` and split/recombine automatically, and so on, etc. and all the usual disclamers)

Note: I know it would be possible to hard-code the name instead of using `DefaultCommandPrefix`, e.g. as `PSReadLine` does (and a bunch of other modules). But, to be honest that feels like a workaround.

Just calling `Verb-OtherNoun` seems fragile to me, as the most recent one is used[3]. So I would imagine that for example just before the call adding an `Import-Module` statement with a module that exports a `Verb-OtherNoun` would cause the wrong (not this module's) cmdlet being called. (Perhaps a more real world scenario is a module being loaded after this module has been loaded, but before calling `Verb-Noun`.)

Is there perhaps some syntax for module-qualifiaction I'm not aware of that would do something akin to `Import-Module`(e.g. `Module\\Verb-Noun` or `Module\Verb+Noun` that would resolve and inject Module's prefix) and now that I think of it, is there some reason why `Module\Verb-Noun` doesn't handle prefixes, or just that no one wrote the code for it? (I can't see how it would break things more than how using `DefaultCommandPrefix` would break v2/v3[2])

[1] https://www.sapien.com/blog/2015/10/23/using-module-qualified-cmdlet-names/

[2] https://github.com/PoshCode/PowerShellPracticeAndStyle/issues/23#issuecomment-106843619

[3] https://stackoverflow.com/a/22259706/13648152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **avoid the problem** by ***not* using a module qualifier**  ***not* using a noun prefix** when you call your module's own functions.

That is, call them as `Verb-Noun`, exactly as named in the target function's implementation.

- This is generally safe, because your own module's functions take precedence over any commands of the same name defined outside your module.

  - The sole exception is if an *alias* defined in the *global scope* happens to have the same name as one of your functions - but that shouldn't normally be a concern, because aliases are used for *short names* that do not follow the verb-noun naming convention.
- It also makes sense in that it allows you to call your functions module-internally with an *invariable* name - a name that doesn't *situationally change*, depending on what the *caller* decided to choose as a noun prefix via `Import-Module -Prefix ...`.

  - **Think of the prefix feature as being a *caller-only* feature** that is unrelated to your module's implementation.

As an aside: As of PowerShell 7.0, declaring a default noun prefix via the `DefaultCommandPrefix` module-manifest property doesn't properly integrate with the [module auto-loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Modules#module-auto-loading) and command-discovery features - see [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/12858).

Comment: Thanks, for clarifying the precedence order. I'll stick to Verb-Noun internally.